# Solving Expressions as part of azure pipeline release name

Tags: azure-pipelines

Im having a problem trying to resolve an expression as part of the pipeline name with azure.

I have created some defined variable as shown below, and when echoing these out they are showing the correct evaluated expressions
[image]

This being said, when then trying to use them as the Release name format it is not resolving the expression and instead using the raw value

Release format name = $(Minor.Major).$(Patch).b$(rev:r)

result is :
$[format('{0}.{1}',variables['Major'], variables['Minor'])].$(Patch).b1
what id expect:
1.0.XbX where the x's are the build patch and rev number

am i missing something in the name box to make it turn into an expression

reference used was https://kasunkodagoda.com/2019/04/03/hidden-gems-in-azure-pipelines-creating-your-own-rev-variable-using-counter-expression-in-azure-pipelines/#8230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As test result and doc description: We could use the pipeline number format in the Azure DevOps **build pipeline** instead of **release pipeline**.

[Release name format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases): We could change the naming scheme by editing the release name format mask, When specifying the format mask, we can use the **pre-defined variables**.

[Build number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#variables): We can also use **user-defined** and **predefined variables** that have a scope of "All" in your number

**Update1**

We cannot use `counter` or `format` in the release pipeline and the blog you shared just show the build result.

Check this doc [adding counter expressions spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/pull/1489/files#diff-364a30a6897fc5fa754cb0755dcaf891): This feature adds a new expression function, `counter`, which will atomically increment a variable value at the start of each build.

And this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter): It cannot be used as part of a condition for a step, job, or stage.

And this is my test result

Build pipeline:

[image]

Release pipeline:

[image]

Comment: I have re-read though the documentation but unless I'm missing something there no reference to being able to run an expression and then use that as the release name. All these variable have to be pre-defined with a fixed value when the Release is started. As there is not reference to using expressions to generate a value im assuming this is not possible so my expression to auto increase the path number for what the user enters as the Major and Minor numbers will not work? so the user will just have to enter the patch number as well

Comment: Hi @ThomasGreener, I have updated, check the update1